# Reading static data in asynchronous task

Tags: database, multithreading, concurrency, static

I am aware about how concurrency can easily create issues in a program.  I have a program that requires an asynchronous task that will save information to a database.  In order to prevent many calls to the database, I cache the data and only save to the database as needed.  Before I commit to adding this functionality, I just want a bit of input on this method.

My question is: Is it safe to read static-data in an Asynchronous task, or is it more inclined to produce bugs? Should I go about doing this another way?

*My apologies if this is a novice question.  I searched for this question and couldn't find the information I needed.*

Comment: What do you mean by "static data"?

Comment: The collection is shared between all instances of a single class, meaning if it's changed anywhere it's reflected in all those instances as well.  Which is why when using concurrency I am not sure if it it could somehow mutate the data in that static collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's pretty safe if done right. Just try to follow several rules:

1. Use [Readers-Writer lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) if you want your collection be consistent at every moment. The benefit of this lock type is that it allows readers to read data almost without performance penalties.
2. Have only one entry point to modify the collection or actual data. If you will use any locking technique, then, of course, don't allow read data from entries that do not use locking.
3. If you use any locking techniques, use one lock per one resource (collection, variable, property). Don't expose this lock to the outside world, use it privately.

Comment: Thank you for the intuitive feedback!  I will implement it using these guidelines.

Comment: It's not intuitive. As you can see, all public static members of any .net class are thread safe — it is mentioned in documentation. And everything else is a common guidelines on how to work with locks and shared state — you can find a lot about this, for example, in CLR via C# book. And you can easily find very useful information just searching info about dead locks and ways to avoid them.